# Bind more than MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS textures in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, bind, game-engine

I am programming a 2D Game Engine, I am using OpenGL (pure, I am not using glut or any other).

If I print this macro: MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS I get 8, and obviously, when I try to bind more than 8 textures, nothing appear in the render area. I was wondering if it is possible to link more than 8 textures?

The function I use to bind a texture is `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID)`.

Comment: Not with a fixed function render pipeline (ie no shaders) that you are using.

Comment: Do you really need to bind more than 8 texture at a time? It is unlikely that you need to bind more than 3 or 4 textures for a single draw command. Most of the time you can reuse the same binding for subsequent draw commands. For example, if you want to draw a background with some sprites, you need only 1 texture binding. You typically need more texture if you're blending 2 textures into one, or copying a texture into another. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Hi @Jean-SimonBrochu I'm trying to make a Game Engine, and in a Game you can see more than 8 textures at time, I wonder how can I do that with OpenGL?

Comment: @AdrianEC: You need to use different textures on different draws. Don't use 20 textures _on the same draw_.

Comment: @AdrianEC: Yes you are confusing a frame and a draw command. When rendering a frame you typically call several draw commands. You can bind a sheep texture to the unit 0, draw your sheep, bind a grass texture to the unit 0, draw your grass... and so on. Then flip your frame to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

`GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS` gives the maximum number of multi-texturing texture units using the old fixed function pipeline. If you are looking to get the maximum number of texture units usable on shaders (E.g. `samplers`), call [`glGetIntegerv`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGet.xhtml) with `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` or `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`. The last one is the preferred value for OpenGL version 3+ and must be at least 16.

Comment: AdrianEC if this answer worked for you consider approving it. @glampert thanks, this worked for me

Comment: This proved helpful to me https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/30101/16132